# R: fread garbling hash data

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I'm using fread to pull in a csv file into Rstudio. When I open the file in a text viewer or excel, the column in question looks like this (values separated by ):

```
0x100000100001092
0x100000100001078
0x100000100001078
0x100000100001092
0x100000100001085
...
```

but once the file has been imported with fread, the column in question looks like this (again, values separated by ):

```
7.205760e+16 7.205760e+16 7.205760e+16 7.205760e+16 7.205760e+16 ...
```

This is the command I'm using to load the data:

```
data <- fread(file_path, sep='auto', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, data.table=FALSE)
```

any idea what's happening and how to preserve the original values?

Comment: Those look like hexadecimal numbers, and `fread` is presumably converting them to ordinal decimal numbers. You could probably specify the `colClasses` as `"character"` if you want the hex format preserved.

Comment: That did it. Thank you, @nrussell!